# Filtering Pandas Dataframe Aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I groupby, and then perform an aggregate calculation to get the mean for:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['year_month', 'company'])
means = grouped.agg({'size':['mean']})
```

Which gives me a dataframe back, but I can't seem to filter it to the specific company and year_month that I want:

```
means[(means['year_month']=='201412')]
```

gives me a KeyError

Comment: Provide a sample code, with data. I have an idea but this line is slightly confusing `means = grouped.agg({'size':['mean']})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are grouping based on `'year_month'` and `'company'` . Hence in the `means` DataFrame, `year_month` and `company` would be part of the index (MutliIndex). You cannot access them as you access other columns.

One method to do this would be to get the values of the level `'year_month'` of index . Example -

```
means.loc[means.index.get_level_values('year_month') == '201412']
```

Demo -

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   A  B   C
0  1  2  10
1  3  4  11
2  5  6  12
3  1  7  13
4  2  8  14
5  1  9  15

In [39]: means = df.groupby(['A','B']).mean()

In [40]: means
Out[40]:
      C
A B
1 2  10
  7  13
  9  15
2 8  14
3 4  11
5 6  12

In [41]: means.loc[means.index.get_level_values('A') == 1]
Out[41]:
      C
A B
1 2  10
  7  13
  9  15
```

Comment: Another method would be to use `.reset_index()` , if you do not want those columns as index. Then you can do what you were trying

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you will end up with a 2 level index. You could try to unstack the aggregated dataframe:

```
means = df.groupby(['year_month', 'company']).agg({'size':['mean']}).unstack(level=1)
```

This should give you a single 'year_month' index, 'company' as columns and your aggregate size as values. You can then slice by the index:

```
means.loc['201412']
```